# Numpy argmax function error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, argmax

I am trying to use the argmax function of numpy to take two argument.
Here is the code:

```
UP = 1 
DOWN = 2 
LEFT = 3 
RIGHT = 4 
actlist = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]

a = numpy.argmax(actlist, lambda a: expected_utility(a,i,j,U))
```

The problem is, one of the arguments is the return value of a function. It returns an integer.
The function `expected_utility(a,i,j,U)` looks like:

```
def expected_utility(a,i,j,U):
    return sum(p*U[i][j] for (k,l,p) in T(i,j,a))
```

If I use lambda with the second parameter of the `argmax` function, I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

If I don't use lambda with the second parameter of the `argmax` function, I am getting the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

I am using Python 3.6.5

Now I am even confused with how `argmax` function even works. What is the role of lambda here.

Comment: Could you explain what `actlist` is and what you are actually trying to do, because you are definately using `argmax` completely wrong and it is hard to guess what you actually are trying to achieve

Comment: actlist is a list of integer

Comment: `UP = 1
DOWN = 2
LEFT = 3
RIGHT = 4
actlist = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]`

Comment: I am trying to implement the Policy iteration algorithm.

Comment: The problem is "lambda a: expected_utility(a,i,j,U)" returns function object, while argmax expects integer as second argument.

Comment: The 2nd argument is supposed to be the `axis`.  Why are you using a function?